# Carrierwave upload image to postgresql table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, carrierwave

I am trying to make an upload profile picture option for my form. I am using carrierwave to do so. While I can run the form with no problems, when I upload and save changes (i think), i check my postgres database column and see that the `avatar` column is still empty. The image has not been saved.

Here is my form:

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put , :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <!-- add profile picture portion -->

  <div><%= f.label :avatar %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>


  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

And here is my uploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Comment: paste the code in your model, and also your carrier wave Uploader class.

Comment: is your avatar field included in the 'permitted params' in your controller?

Comment: @joshua.paling I only have one controller so far and that is the ApplicationController

Comment: @joshua.paling Well I do have another one but it is to generate a separate view. Devise did a lot fo work for me and a controller wasnt generated. All i did so far was follow the devise and carrierwave readme on github

Comment: Are you following this tutorial? https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-carrierwave-with-devise Did you add the 'configure_permitted_parameters' to your application controller?

Comment: @joshua.paling i wasnt following that tutorial but that is a good find! i can try it out! thanks!